# How can I say last last month?

Tags: expressions

How can I say last last month?

> the previous month of last month?
>
> the prior month of the last month?
>
> For example, What was the number of people visited stackoverflow.com in the previous month of last month?

2 months ago is not the answer I am looking for.

Comment: You should try to get ereyestermonth trending :)

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ereyesterday

Comment: So you'll use *ereyestermonth*? Please say yes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "The month before last".

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend specifying the month. For example "in November 2021".

"The month before last" is fine in spoken conversation, but if you were writing something which a reader might come across months later, it would be confusing or misleading. Specifying the month avoids that problem.